# For $X$ and $Y$ normed linear spaces and $T\in\mathcal{L}(X,Y)$, show that $||T||=\sup\{||T(w)||:w\in X, ||w||\leq 1\}.$

Tags: functional-analysis

For $X$ and $Y$ normed linear spaces and $T\in\mathcal{L}(X,Y)$, show that $$||T||=\sup\{||T(w)||:w\in X, ||w||\leq 1\}.$$ where $\mathcal{L}$ denotes the bounded linear space.

Definition: Let $X$ and $Y$ be normed linear spaces. A linear operator $T:X\to Y$ is said to be bounded provided there exist $M\geq 0$ for which
$$||Tx||\leq M||x||,\forall x\in X.$$
The infimum of all such $M$ is called the operator norm of $T$ and denoted by $||T||$. THe collection of bounded linear oprtators from $X$ to $Y$ is denoted by
$\mathcal{L}(X,Y)$

Since $T\in \mathcal{L}(X,Y)$, therefore
$$||Tw||\leq ||T|| ||w||$$
$$\frac{||Tw||}{||w||}\leq ||T||$$
$$||T\bigg(\frac{w}{||w||}\bigg)||\leq ||T||$$

Can I get some hints? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your definition of $\| T \|$?

Comment: This is problem 11 chapter 13 HL Royden Fourth edition.

Comment: Not every one has the book. You should give the definition.

Comment: Please have a look I have added the definition.